# How to capture return code (not exit code)

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that execute some process and return a number based on the job status. This script is triggered on the back background.

i.e.

```
ksh -x myscript.sh 20150102 &
```

My question is how can I get the return code of the background process? Is there a way to get return code like for exit code `$?`

Comment: Try [`wait`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?wait+3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wait`:

```
# Start the job:
ksh -x myscript.sh 20150102 &

# Save its process ID
job_pid=$!

# Do some other stuff in the meantime
asdf ghjk
zxcv qwer

# Later, when you want to know what its exit status was:
wait $job_pid
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Something may have gone wrong" >&2
else
    echo "The world is perfect." >&2
fi
```

In this context, I'm considering "return code" and "exit code" synonymous. If you mean the terms to have different meanings from each other then I've misunderstood you, but I can't think what the difference might be.

Comment: In my case the exit code doesn't reflect return code. My script triggers some job remotely nd gets return code from the remote process. So even if the remote code was a failure, I would still get "$?" return 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "return code" and what do you mean by "exit code"? They mean the same thing to me. If I ran something that failed, I would expect a non-zero exit status which is to say a non-zero `$?`. You mean something different than that by "return code" and/or "exit code"?

Comment: Ok I think I was confused with return code being diff from exit code. But if I am spawning multiple background process how can I get return/exit code for each one of them?

Comment: You can get the exit status of each one of them as per my answer using `wait`!

Comment: Please not that /bin/sh does not handle wait the same as /bin/bash.  It does not report the PID return code as its own upon state change of the PID.